# Facing frequent issues with Kurento media server one 2 one calling app

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I am facing this frequently, and not able to figure out why, as sometimes it appears and sometimes it get resolved on its own. Can anyone please help?

Following is the error in the logs of Kurento-media-server.

[Kurento-media-server-log](http://pastebin.com/xbn2jVb0)

basically sometime I get ICE_GATHER_CANDIDATE error. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed kurento 6.6.0. Also I have configured google stun server: `stun4.l.google.com` with port `19302`.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling IPv6 in your box. Edit `sysctl.conf` with

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

add the following at the bottom of the file

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

save and run `sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast but I read this from the mailing list of Kurento but the issue keeps on appearning, thats why I posted this question I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Kurento 6.6.0

Comment: @BilboBaggins Please complete your question with things that you've tried then. The more info you provide, the easier it will be for others to help you. My next suggestion is to try reinstalling the whole box, so if you've tried that already...

Comment: @BilboBaggins Some users have also reported that that was the only thing that worked for them, apart from the IPv6 thing. There's also a [bugtracker issue](https://github.com/Kurento/bugtracker/issues/102) where I've posted the IPv6 solution.

Comment: I have one more question I am posting it separately :)

Comment: here is the link for my next question :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089696/how-to-record-my-own-video-and-use-it-for-later-viewing-using-kurento